# Any way to do this?

Tags: python-3.x

Searched for hours :/

```
x0,x1,x2=1,2,3
for i in range(3):
    xi=xi+1
print(x1,x2,x3)
>2 3 4
```

Is there a way to do this with "for" method?

Comment: It is already using for. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean it does not work because its bovious xi does not exist my question is is there a way to make it work using xi to call x1 and then x2 , x3 ...

Comment: Use a list instead of 3 separate variables.

Comment: Ah, I missed that and now get the question

Comment: or you could use 3 lists. x=[1], y=[2],  z=[3]

Comment: you should check "Python loop over an array" in python, and I think you will find !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
x=1
y=2
z=3
x,y,z = map(lambda i: i+1, [x,y,z])
```

Comment: The OP is asking an implementation using for, but noice :D

Comment: ah, then its `x,y,z = [i+1 for i in x,y,z]`

Comment: Ho sweet it does not uses list thanks !!! and i can get over for using this

Answer (score 2):

Use a list to access items by index:

```
x = [1,2,3]
for i, item in enumerate(x):    # Enumerate will give the index and item at that index
    x[i] = item + 1
```

Or a bit more like C:

```
for i in range(length(x)):    # Go over the whole list
    x[i] = x[i] + 1           # Also x[i] += 1
```

Comment: Nice but using list is problematic for me (memory)

Comment: @GabrielT Why is the memory problematic?

Answer (score 0):

From Rocket Hazmat's comment, use a list instead of 3 separate variables to store your values. This will also fix your issue where you can't call "xi" because that doesn't exist.

Something like this:

```
values = [1,2,3]
for i in range(3):
    values[i] = values[i] + 1
```